# Binding Keyup to an Element using jQuery extension and jquery.on

Tags: data-binding, jquery-plugins, keypress, jquery

This seems very simple, but for some reason it's not working as expected.

I am trying to make a very simple jQuery extension/plugin which allows me to simply reduce my lines of code when requiring a trigger on an `enter` key (and a similar for an `escape`)

Here's my code:

```
$.fn.enterListen = function (callBack) {
    $(this).on('keyup', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            callBack;
            // $(this).enterListen(callBack); // trying to rebind...
        };
    })
};
```

Then when an element is dynamically created with jquery we might do something like:

```
var input = $('<input'>).enterListen(function (){ alert("Enter was pressed"); });
$(input).appendTo('body');
```

Now we've added an input element to the page, in which we can type and when `enter` is pressed it triggers the alert.

This works, except, only once.

You can see a commented out line in my code above where I am trying to rebind the function the the element after the `enter` trigger is activated, and even that doesn't make it work a second time.

You can press as many other keys as you like before pressing `Enter`, but as soon as you do, it seems to unbind the `keyup` event.

IF... however, I run it like this:

```
function isEnter(e, ele) {
    if ((e * 1) == 13) {
        $(ele).click();
    };
};
```

Called by:

```
var input = $('<input'>).on('keyup', function (e) { isEnter(e.keyCode, $(ok)) });
$(input).appendTo('body');
```

It works fine, but to me it is clumsier in the code, I am trying to create a library of extensions to make the inner coding of this project a bit shorter... perhaps I am just putting too much time into something I needn't...

Anyway, if anyone could shed any light on why the event becomes unbound, that'd be lovely!

Comment: Few remarks: 1) use e.which instead of e.keyCode: http://api.jquery.com/event.which/ 2) also `callBack;` will not be executed, use `callBack()` instead.

Comment: I think `callback;` was a typo, thank for the pointer on `.which` duly noted :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a jQuery plugin, `this` is the jQuery object, no need to rewrap it. `e.which` is normalized in jQuery. To execute a function you need parenthesis `()`. And most importantly, you need to return `this` otherwise the `input` variable will be undefined, and if you intend to do stuff inside your plugin with selectors containing multiple elements, you need to return `this.each(function() { ... })` etc. as explained in the [plugin authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) documentation from jQuery.

```
$.fn.enterListen = function (callBack) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).on('keyup', function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                callBack();
            }
        });
    });
};

var input = $('<input />').enterListen(function (){ 
    alert("Enter was pressed"); 
});

input.appendTo('body');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YEvxg/4/)